# D3JS filler gauge

Tags: javascript, d3.js, gauge

Most of the gauge charts are donuts shape, but I am looking to a fill bar dynamic graph similar to the one [here](http://www.ikangae.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Gauge_charts.png).

I am not sure if there is any d3 example which can be dynamic referenced to a dynamic value such as the mouse position as I made in [this JSfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/iblasi/cvxx069t/) where a donut shape gauge is used with the code I found on http://bl.ocks.org/tomerd/1499279 example with some modifications:

```
var gauges = [];

var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;

function createGauge(name, label, min, max)
{
    var config = 
    {
        size: 120,
        label: label,
        min: undefined != min ? min : 0,
        max: undefined != max ? max : 100,
        minorTicks: 5
    }

    gauges[name] = new Gauge(name + "GaugeContainer", config);
    gauges[name].render();
}

function createGauges()
{
    createGauge("xMouse", "X - Mouse");
    createGauge("yMouse", "Y - Mouse");
}

function initialize()
{
    createGauges();
    $( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
        gauges["xMouse"].redraw(100*event.pageX/w);
        gauges["yMouse"].redraw(100*event.pageY/h);
    });
}
```

I know that there are other SVG such as the rectangle, but which is the best way to make a "filler bar" gauge?

[image]

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4jr9myha/) is something I quickly put together which is similar to your gauge Fiddle but using bars. Hopefully you can pick out a few things from it that could be of help.

Comment: @JSBob that's a nice example! It works very well and it exactly a new widget available for D3JS developers. Thank you!